# Apple Object Capture Photogrammetry- texture UV

Tags: xcode, 3d, realitykit

The textures on Apple Object Capture Photogrammetry API:
https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/object-capture/

Are outputted like the attachment bellow.

My goal is to be able to change each texture of the shoe. Ex, change the green rubber texture to a plastic orange. How can I modify the scan and texture to be able to do this?

I guess I would need to create islands on the mesh and remap the UV layout?

[image][image]